# Subset image collection by specific dates, cannot interpret data Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, date

I am trying to subset an image collection by a list of dates. However, I keep getting the error that my dates are not interpretable.

The date list comes from an imported csv with a list of dates.

```
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection('users/user/lu_long_pres_ES');
var pts_buffer = pts.map(bufferPoints(500, false));


//read in image collection
var climate = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE")
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)

///read in date list and subset image collection to dates
var dates = ee.FeatureCollection('users/user/dates')
var date2list = dates.reduceColumns({
                    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList().repeat(1),
                    selectors: ['date']
                  })
                   .get('list');

var date_list = ee.List(date2list).map(function(date){return ee.Date(date).millis()});
print(date_list)

var climate = climate.map(function(image){
  return image.set('simpleTime', ee.Date(image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')).millis());
});

var climate_sub = climate.filter(ee.Filter.inList("simpleTime", date_list));
```

How can I convert the column of dates from the csv to a list of dates interpretable by google earth engine?

[The csv with dates is linked here.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/ckglidden/dates)

The full code can be found here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/74db7bc86d1efeee21c32da0357e8d40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two tricks you need to modify to the original script so it can work fine. The first one is that in the original script the `date2list` object corresponds to a list with the dates inside another list (you can print the object to analyse its structure in the console). So to fix this, you should `flatten` the list to get rid of the nested structure. Afterwards, you should use `ee.Date.parse` to convert the String into a Date. However, the second trick is that the date entries contain a pair of double quotes (`""`), so you need to include these quotes in the format string. Here's the only modifications you need to make to your script so it works:

```
var date2list = ee.List(dates.reduceColumns({
                    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList().repeat(1),
                    selectors: ['date']
                  })
                   .get('list'))
                   .flatten();

var date_list = date2list.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date.parse({format:'"y-M-d"',
                        date: ee.String(date)})
                        .millis();
});
```